# loading fashion_mnist data takes too much time

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mnist

I am using python 3.6.6, tensorflow 1.11.0, and keras 2.1.6 on Windows 10
Following the below blog as a guideline to import and load the data.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification

The shell IDLE prints too much output and continues indefinitely.

This line in my code seems to be the issue:

```
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

Below are a few lines of output from my shell IDLE execution:

1.11.0

```
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz

    8192/26421880 [..............................] - ETA: 0s
   16384/26421880 [..............................] - ETA: 2:05
  172032/26421880 [..............................] - ETA: 21s 
  450560/26421880 [..............................] - ETA: 11s
  933888/26421880 [>.............................] - ETA: 7s 
 1507328/26421880 [>.............................] - ETA: 5s
 2056192/26421880 [=>............................] - ETA: 4s
 2670592/26421880 [==>...........................] - ETA: 4s
 3358720/26421880 [==>...........................] - ETA: 3s
 3833856/26421880 [===>..........................] - ETA: 3s
 4259840/26421880 [===>..........................] - ETA: 3s
 4489216/26421880 [====>.........................] - ETA: 3s
 4931584/26421880 [====>.........................] - ETA: 3s
 4997120/26421880 [====>.........................] - ETA: 3s
 5005312/26421880 [====>.........................] - ETA: 3s
 5013504/26421880 [====>.........................] - ETA: 4s
 5021696/26421880 [====>.........................] - ETA: 4s
 5029888/26421880 [====>.........................] - ETA: 4s
 5038080/26421880 [====>.........................]
```

Why the shell does not stop?
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Its downloading the data, it only needs to happen once, how long did you wait?

Comment: I waited 25-30 minutes.  Is there a way to stop shell IDLE from printing all those lines?

Comment: Update: I let it run for over 3 hours and 10 minutes.  It did not finish downloading.  Something is probably wrong here.  In the past I used mnist handwritten digits to train nets and the whole process took about 10-12 minutes. This is my first experience of using tensorflow :(

Comment: I only see that your internet connection might be very slow, its just a 26 MB file. About the shell issue, that's an IDLE problem, run your code in a terminal

Comment: Thank you Matias. Your comments were very helpful.  I ran it in the "python command line" and it went very smooth (it took just 3 seconds).  If you make an answer then I choose it as the best one. In the past 3 days, I tried different approaches like installing mnist_reader package which didn't go well.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe IDLE's shell is not fast enough and might be slowing down the file download, try running the same python code from a terminal, as it will download the file and this needs to be done only once.

Answer (score 0):

To execute Matias Valdenegro's answer of loading outside IDLE you can open **Python's Command Line** (or on **Windows' Command Line** type `python` and press Enter).
Then type
`import tensorflow as tf`
Press Enter and type:
`tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()`
Press Enter, wait, and in the end you're ready to use mnist on IDLE without having to load again.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue & does the following on Window machine -

1. Get into Python (Shell) Command line Interface by typing python. Then in Python shell run below mentioned commands..

> ```
> from keras.datasets import mnist
> (train_images,train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
> ```

This took only 61 seconds (this may take less than that if your net speed is on higher side...) Once this is done then you can run your program from IDLE as well & then it will run quickly at least won't get stuck on downloading the dataset.... Matias Valdenegro also suggesting the same....